# Почему не работает ивент DownloadProgressChanged в C#, WebClient?

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет.
Есть следующий код:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChangedEvent);
wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://site.ru/" + file), file, file);
```

Есть функции:

```
public void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write("Файл загружен");
}

public void DownloadProgressChangedEvent(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Write("Файл загружается");
}
```

Почему функция DownloadFileCompleted отрабатывает после загрузки файла, а DownloadProgressChangedEvent во время загрузки нет? Она попросту не вызывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вполне возможно, что загрузка была неудачной.

Попробуйте так:

```
public void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        Console.Write("Ошибка: " + e.Error.ToString());
    else
        Console.Write("Файл загружен");
}
```

Comment: Господи, код 404 отдает, еще вчера , пока писал код, смотрел в логах веб-сервера результаты запросов, а сегодня как то в голову не пришло.
Спасибо большое)

Comment: @kompas: Пожалуйста! Контроль ошибок — наше всё.